# Visual Studio Environment

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on my PC. I published by website from VS2015 via it's Publish feature to my shared hosting site. It starts to copy files but shows an error below:

Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid

I read in one of the answers that VS environment should be changed but there is no further detail as to how to change VS Environment, can someone assist please?

Comment: The full error is:

Comment: Adding database (data source=SQL5019.Smarterasp.net;initial catalog=DB_9FCCF7_LeafletDist;user id=DB_9FCCF7_LeafletDist_admin)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,5): Error ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD: Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.

Comment: Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.

  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.)
Publish failed to deploy.